# Show product information on right side

Tags: css, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on this website which uses woocommerce. As I've added a product it's featured image and gallery image shows on the left side but the product details are not on the right but they are shown below the gallery images.
 Here are some screenshots:
[image]
In the image above you can see black space on the right. The content that is supposed to be shown here is in the picture below:[image]Here is the link to this page: https://www.embroyalluxury.com/shop/03-peachy-pastel/.
Now if I zoom out the page using my browser zoom it goes to the right. So I understand this has something to do with responsiveness of this website but the client has this 13" MacBook and I'm not a coder. So can anyone tell me how to get this done? I can insert the code in style.css or custom .css section the theme options have provided.

Comment: Found this when searching for how to put product on the right.  Here is what worked for me: (add the following to additional CSS)   .woocommerce-product-gallery { 
 float:right !important;
}

.summary {
 float:left !important;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to chave line number 12557 in your style.css. Go to your style.css file and search for the code bellow and delete it.

```
 .woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
    width: 50% !important;
}
```

Is your theme really responsive? I think your theme have a big issue with responsive.